# Filtering records from lists

Tags: python, list

I am new to python and wanted to have some help, would appreciate if someone could help,

I have a below python list of list, and I want to form a new list which will contain the last sublist based on first element of sublist, for ex. ISIN=BE0974302342, I want to add only ['BE0974302342', 21, 19, 0, 2, 0] to new list and ignore all first occurrences, I thought of using for loops to compare first element of every sublist with the first element of the second sublist, but that would not be a clean way, could this be achieved using list comprehension or some builtin method?

```
my_list = [['BE0974302342', 21, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
           ['BE0974302342', 21, 19, 0, 0, 0], 
           ['BE0974302342', 21, 19, 0, 2, 0], 
           ['FR0000073843', 22, 19, 0, 2, 0], 
           ['FR0000073843', 22, 20, 0, 2, 0], 
           ['FR0000073843', 22, 20, 0, 2, 0], 
           ['FR0000076861', 21, 20, 0, 2, 0], 
           ['FR0000076861', 21, 18, 0, 2, 0], 
           ['FR0000076861', 21, 18, 3, 2, 0], 
           ['FR0000076861', 21, 18, 3, 3, 0]]

 new_list = [['BE0974302342', 21, 19, 0, 2, 0], 
             ['FR0000073843', 22, 20, 0, 2, 0], 
             ['FR0000076861', 21, 18, 3, 3, 0]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the sublists by the first element, and keep the last sublist of each group:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

[list(v)[-1] for _,v in groupby(my_list, key=itemgetter(0))]
```

**Output**

```
[['BE0974302342', 21, 19, 0, 2, 0],
 ['FR0000073843', 22, 20, 0, 2, 0],
 ['FR0000076861', 21, 18, 3, 3, 0]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
my_list = [['BE0974302342', 21, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
           ['BE0974302342', 21, 19, 0, 0, 0], 
           ['BE0974302342', 21, 19, 0, 2, 0], 
           ['FR0000073843', 22, 19, 0, 2, 0], 
           ['FR0000073843', 22, 20, 0, 2, 0], 
           ['FR0000073843', 22, 20, 0, 2, 0], 
           ['FR0000076861', 21, 20, 0, 2, 0], 
           ['FR0000076861', 21, 18, 0, 2, 0], 
           ['FR0000076861', 21, 18, 3, 2, 0], 
           ['FR0000076861', 21, 18, 3, 3, 0]]

my_list_dict = {}
new_list = []

# Unique Items with id as key and rest as values
for item in my_list:
    my_list_dict[item[0]] = item[1:]

# Convert them back to a list
for k,v in my_list_dict.items():
    new_list.append([k,*v])

print(new_list)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative approach, which doesn't require `itertools`:

```
tmp = { x[0]:x for x in my_list }
new_list = list(tmp.values())
```

The `tmp` dict contains the last occurrence of the first element in the sublists. The only catch is that the sublists will appear in an order different from the original input:

```
new_list
=> [['FR0000073843', 22, 20, 0, 2, 0],
    ['FR0000076861', 21, 18, 3, 3, 0],
    ['BE0974302342', 21, 19, 0, 2, 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution, the order will not matter as I would be referring the records using the key

Answer (score 2):

**one-liner** (without using any import):

```
print(list({(x[0]): x for x in my_list}.values()))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[['BE0974302342', 21, 19, 0, 2, 0], ['FR0000073843', 22, 20, 0, 2, 0], 
 ['FR0000076861', 21, 18, 3, 3, 0]]
```

**Elaboration**:

The idea is to map every first element of the nested list with the list itself as a `key-val` pair, since dict can not have duplicate keys it will handle it for us:

```
print({x[0]: x for x in my_list})
```

Would return something like:

```
{'BE0974302342': ['BE0974302342', 21, 19, 0, 2, 0], 'FR0000073843': ['FR0000073843', 22, 20, 0, 2, 0], 'FR0000076861': ['FR0000076861', 21, 18, 3, 3, 0]}
```

Now we, already have the unique `key-val` paired of lists, getting the values from the `dict` would get us the unique nested lists:

```
print({x[0]: x for x in my_list}.values())
```

Which would give us a `dict` of `list`:

```
dict_values([['BE0974302342', 21, 19, 0, 2, 0], ['FR0000073843', 22, 20, 0, 2, 0], ['FR0000076861', 21, 18, 3, 3, 0]])
```

We can convert it to a list now:

```
print(list({(x[0]): x for x in my_list}.values()))
```

This would simply get us the required unique lists based on the first element inside them:

```
[['BE0974302342', 21, 19, 0, 2, 0], ['FR0000073843', 22, 20, 0, 2, 0], 
 ['FR0000076861', 21, 18, 3, 3, 0]]
```